# Prevent pasting invalid strings with ng-past directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an
    `<input type="number">`
tag in which I would like to have only integer numbers. I have been able to prevent the insertion of '-', 'e' and '.' on keypress, but I couldn't do that on paste event. How can I validate a pasted string?

AngularJS version used is 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Make Directive. Try this way

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" class="container">

  <p>Demo of AngularJS Numbers Only Directive</p>

  <p>Input below will accept only numbers.</p>

  <p><input type="text" ng-model="val" numbers-only class="form-control" /></p>


</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
```

});